# selecting and removing multiple items from flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist which looks like this:

```
  <FlatList
    numColumns={3}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    data={dataset}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    extraData={selectedId}
    renderItem={renderItem}
  />
```

users can select 1 or more items, and if the item is already selected then it will be removed

I can add many items and remove them too, however, the problem is if I select an Item, I cant remove it directly I need to select another item, then the previously chosen item will be removed.

but I cant remove it if I click on the same item again. I have to choose another item then the older item will be removed, while the other item is added.

my renderItem:

```
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={item.selected ? styles.setItemItemSlt : styles.setItemItem}
        onPress={() => [
          setSelectedId(item.id),
          onPressBtn({ item }, item.selected),
        ]}
      >
        <Image style={styles.setItemItemImage} source={item.icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

also:

```
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
```

and the array looks like this:

```
    const [dataset, setItem] = useState([
        {
          id: 1,
          icon: require("../../src/assets/png/egg.png"),
          name: "egg",
          selected: false,
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
      ]);
```

and:

```
  const onPressBtn = ({ item }) => {
    // if it has been selected remove it
    if (item.selected) {
      item.selected = false;
    }
    // if it is not in the list add it
    else {
      item.selected = true;
    }
  };
```

how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, It will remove selection if already selected

```
// add index here
const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        .....
        onPress={() => [
          .....
          onPressBtn(item, index), // send index as param
        ]}
      >
        .........
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

const onPressBtn = (item, index ) => {
    const data = [...allergens];
    data[index].selected = !data[index].selected;
    allergy(data); // reset data here to state   
};
```

Comment: thank you this worked fine I had to reset the data set.